# a = b = c coding standards

Tags: c#, coding-style

I'm in charge of creating  coding standards and doing code reviews within my organization.

I came cross something within our source code like this:

```
object.Property = myVar1 = myVar2;
```

I don't personally do this because I find it confusing.  I see this and I want to read it like this:

```
object.Property = myVar1 == myVar2;
```

Now I know what it's doing:  It assigns myVar to myVar2 and then object.Property to myVar2.  The coding standards document doesn't explicitly state whether or not you can do this.  It does state however to not assign variables within an if statement.

I guess my question is, is it bad enough style to draw out as a coding practice to not do it?  I don't like making code standard policies "just because I said so"

Edited to better explain my understanding

Comment: Code is meant for humans to read and rarely for computers to execute. If there's ambiguity fix it :)

Comment: As you have already said, its confusing... That's a good reason for me to put it as a thing to avoid

Comment: @Mehrdad can't remember the citation now :P

Comment: @Jesus: It's from SICP. :P Might be worth mentioning that. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad yeah I had forgotten the source thanks

Comment: Obligatory Lippert blog item: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/11/chaining-simple-assignments-is-not-so-simple.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This so-called "chained assignment" is indeed controversial and there are quite a few questions on SO that address it.

It is a byproduct of assignment being an expression and not a statement, as you know, and to many people it can be confusing.

It many languages it is somewhat dangerous to novices.  In languages where `[]` is a constructor for empty array objects, writing

```
a = b = []
```

makes `a` and `b` reference the same object.  Novices tend to think it makes two separate empty arrays which can be filled independently.  Not so!  The C# equivalent,

```
a = b = new SomethingOrOther();
```

is arguably far less likely to occur, since `a` and `b` would be more likely to be initialized at the point of declaration, and such double *assignments* would be rarer, and furthermore C# programmers are more likely to see the obvious sharing in this case.

A good rationale for instituting a prohibition against this is three-fold:

1. It is completely unnecessary.
2. It is error-prone (as in the array example above).

When you encounter error-prone constructs, you should avoid them because in avoiding them, you will never make that particular error.  Granted, in C#, it may be far less error prone than in other languages.

Comment: The fact that people make the array mistake is completely irrelevant to C# though...

Answer (score 8):

I always wrap equality expressions in parentheses:

```
object.Property = (myVar1 == myVar2);
```

This draws attention to the fact that it's not an assignment.

Answer (score 2):

That's (usually) nothing to worry about, in C#.

Unless your variable is `bool` (in which case you should separate it into two statements either way), that **isn't error-prone** -- only one of the two will ever work correctly, so there's no danger of "accidentally" omitting or typing an extra `=`.

Conclusion: Don't worry about non-boolean cases.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, kudos to you for not assuming "my way is the right way".  This kind of question is very subjective and devs will have different (and usually strong) opinions.

I will say that I try to avoid confusing code, but statements like this can (in some scenarios) make the code more readable by collapsing a large number of statements into fewer statements.  Not always true, but I think it is sometimes.

My *opinion* is not to exclude this kind of statement in your coding standard, and try to be as inclusive of different coding styles as you can be (except for blatantly unreadable or confusing code).

I have been involved in a lot more "coding standards" discussions than I would like, and I find that they tend to cause a lot more friction than the problems they are aiming to solve.

Comment: Thanks, I try my to keep in mind that the "coding standards" are really there to give our projects a certain consistency that we can expect as developers, and I don't want to have pedantic conversations around "my opinion vs. your opinion"

Comment: Yes, it's good to see people thinking through this type of thing!

Answer (score 2):

Since I run across times when I would *want* `a = b = c` *very rarely* I just write it as two separate statements. (This is often times just as well for me because I like to *not re-assign* variables when possible, making the assignment only in the declaration, and I only declare one variable per variable declaration.)

Then, if I *do* come across `a = b == c` I just take that as being "assign the result of the equality to a" and don't even think twice about it (as my coding style doesn't include `a = b = c`).

However, this error is minimized in C# because, except when dealing with boolean types (for a, b, *and* c), the compiler will complain because the types will be amiss.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I know what it's doing: It assigns myVar to myVar2 and then object.Property to myVar1

Your understand is incorrect, the compiler don't do that.
Because `assignment expressions` return a value, therefore, in your example, `object.Property` is assigned with the return value of assignment expression `myVar1 = myVar2`. **NOT** assign `myVar2` to `myVar1` and thenn `myVar1` to `object.Property`

So that, there's no confusion between 2 statement that you have given. But, if your variables do not have the same type, you should use *parentheses* to make your code readable.

```
object.Property = myVar1 == myVar2;
```

Answer (score 1):

*As this is about coding style this is very much IMHO*

Almost any language feature can be seen as confusing or wonderful depending on the dev. Some people thinks that operator overloading (or generics, closures, higher-order functions and so on) is the road to hell, other sees it as a good tool to create succint and readable code.

If this is a common pattern in your code base chances are your devs are comfortable with the semantics of this pattern. In this case I would think a recommendation against it might be seen as counter-productive.

If it is an uncommon pattern in your code base this *might* be a confusing pattern and therefore it can be good to recommend against and search for the places where this pattern is used and consider refactoring.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of where I am right now... it's the first time I've seen it and couldn't think of a good reason why to not accept it as a viable solution.  Ultimately, I'm going to say nothing about as it's just not that common and I'd rather my devs to follow the bigger style standards and not get hung up on this kind of stuff.